# To append columns from file 1 to 3 for each row that the first cell of that row matches ow create a new row and then append

Tags: text-processing

I have four CSV files as examples given below; I want to append columns from file 1 to 3 for each row that the first cell of that row matches ow create a new row and then append.

file1:

```
N,Mon,Tue,Wed
1,A,B,C
2,D,E,F
3,I,J,X
```

file2:

```
N,Mon,Tue,Wed
3,D,E,F
5,O,P,q
1,D,E,K
```

file3

```
N,Mon,Tue,Wed
2,B,E,J
6,L,D,O
3,I,J,B
```

My output should be as below

```
N, Mon, Tue, Wed, Mon, Tue, Wed, Mon, Tue, Wed
1, A, B, C, D, E, F , , ,
2, D, E, F, , , , B, E, J
3, I, J, K, D, E, F, I, J, B
5, , , , O, P, q, , , 
6, , , , , , , L, D, O
```

```
Client Name,Monday 08/18,Tuesday 08/19,Wednesday 08/20,Thursday 08/21,Friday 08/22,Saturday 08/23,Sunday 08/24,Monday 08/25
ns2.advancemags.com->/var,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B; ,,,,,,,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B;
ns2.advancemags.com->/usr,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B; ,,,,,,,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B;
ns2.advancemags.com->/,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B; ,,,,,,,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B;
ns2.advancemags.com->/boot,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B; ,,,,,,,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Mon_B Synthetic_Full 0B;
ns3.advancemags.com->/boot,,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Tue_C Synthetic_Full 0B; ,,,,,,
ns3.advancemags.com->/,,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Tue_C Synthetic_Full 0B; ,,,,,,
ns3.advancemags.com->/usr,,Successful Full FS_UNIX_Tue_C Synthetic_Full 0B; ,,,,,,
```

Comment: Where `I, J, K` in `1` comes from?

Comment: sorry have edited output table.

Comment: You have 4 files, but header only output only three `Mon, Tue, Wed`? `file3` also has two `2` but the ouput only show one? `file4` has `2` but not shown in output.

Comment: edited the question, I hope this looks good. please ignore the previous one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In bash, define a function

```
function hsort { 
head -n +1 "$1" ; sort <(tail -n +2 "$1"); 
}
```

then

```
join -a1 -a2 -t, -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,2.2,2.3,2.4 \
<(join -a1 -a2 -t, -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(hsort file1) <(hsort file2)) \
<(hsort file3) | sed 's/,/, /g'
```

giving

```
N, Mon, Tue, Wed, Mon, Tue, Wed, Mon, Tue, Wed
1, A, B, C, D, E, K, , , 
2, D, E, F, , , , B, E, J
3, I, J, X, D, E, F, I, J, B
5, , , , O, P, q, , , 
6, , , , , , , L, D, O
```

[NOTE: your file2 has `D,E,K` in row 1 not `D,E,F` as shown in the desired output.]

---

To extend to four files is straightforward

```
join -a1 -a2 -t, -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,1.7,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.6,2.7 \
<(join -a1 -a2 -t, -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(hsort file1) <(hsort file2)) \
<(join -a1 -a2 -t, -o0,1.2,1.3,1.4,2.2,2.3,2.4 <(hsort file3) <(hsort file4)) | 
sed 's/,/, /g'
```

Handling *more* than four files would require a whole additional level of joining and start to look ugly pretty quickly - I would not recommend this method in that case.

Comment: script looks good to me. Please let me know how can I implement this with 5 files with each file having data like shown in question.

Comment: Extension to 4 files isfairly straightforward (see edit above). Handling more than four files would require a whole additional level of joining and start to look ugly pretty quickly - I would not recommend this method in that case.